# Accessing an object passed through props in the component of ReactNative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm very new to ReactNative and not great on my javascript either, so forgive me if this is dumb (i have searched all over google and stackoverflow and can't seem to find the direct answer to my question):

I have a simple component I've defined:

```
export default class SPlanet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {

    const planet = this.props ? this.props.planet : null;
    console.log(planet);

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.planet}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

It's called in the app.js like:

```
<SPlanet planet={planetDB.Atraxia}/>
```

and that object is defined like this:

```
const planetDB = {
  Atraxia : {
    type : "gas",
    name : "Atraxia",
    economy : 10,
    resources : 3,
    loyalty : "70%",
    side : "enemy"
  },
}
```

Now this basically works (it throws no errors). it will simply pass the object to the console log, but won't display anything in the text.

But what if i just want to show the name? I've tried

```
  console.log(planet.name);
```

but throws an error: "undefined is not an object"

I also tried sending it as a simple array and calling it like

```
  console.log(planet[0]);
```

but I get the same error.

I'm sure this is a stupid mistake on my part where I'm missing something foundational to the languages, but I'm stumped. Help?

Comment: try with `if (planet) console.log(planet.name);`; that way if the planet props is not passed when your component get called the first time, it won't fail

Comment: @Ben thanks for the tip, that's a good idea to keep it from crashing while I'm testing it out. But any idea on how to get that object data?

Comment: as said, your code should work, you should be able to access your properties **if** planet props is not null. That is, depending on your code, and because react rerenders, I'm just expecting it to fail because it is not passed the first time you call the component (if product is somehow null, `console.log(product)` will pass, `console.log(product.name)` won't, but could if after rerendering the props get effectively passed). Try with this gard, you'll probably see a difference; if not, send more of your code (`app.js`)

Comment: @Ben You were correct, planet was showing up null. So how do I get it to pass the props?

Comment: as said, your code should work, but for further help, as mentionned, `send more of your code (app.js)`

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it to no end, I came upon this:

```
const planetDB = {
  "Atraxia" : {
    type : "gas",
    name : "Atraxia",
    economy : 10,
    resources : 3,
    loyalty : "70%",
    side : "enemy"
  },
}
```

By adding quotations around the planet name, suddenly now it works. BUt I dont't know why. If somone can explain to me why, I'll mark them as the answer.

Comment: Quotations would be important if you were storing planetDb as a json object otherwise they change nothing, since clearly the object is inside a js file. What I am wondering is what is working, because I see problems with `<Text>` tag, you are passing in children as an object, so by saying "It's working", are you referring to the `console.log`?

Comment: @IsaacSekamatte, Huh, I hadn't thought of that. It worked that way on the parent screen and doesn't throw any errors, and it would display the object as a concatenated string (gasAtraxia10370%enemy). It did that even before I put the quotation marks in, it would just never let me see the values of individual properties in my SPlanet component, and would crash if i tried to even console.log the individual properties.